# Problem with gradient of actor in an Actor Critic algorithm using linear function approximation

Tags: vector-analysis, machine-learning

I have a problem updating $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (the weights vector for the actor in an actor critic algorithm). I know the gradient of $ln(\pi(a|s,\boldsymbol{ \theta }) = \mathbf{x}(s,a) - \sum_b{\pi(b|s,\boldsymbol{\theta})*\mathbf{x}(s,b)} $where the index b represent each of the possible actions. The result of this difference is always $0$. I think I know why: it is because $\mathbf{x}(s,b)$ is equal for all actions so I can take it out of the sum and because the summation of all the $\pi(b|s,\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is equal to 1 then the result is equal to $\mathbf{x}(s,a) - \mathbf{x}(s,a) = 0$. I'm using stack features technique. I have search through various sources like coursera, google etc. but I cannot find a solution. My question is: How to encode $\mathbf{x}(s,a)$ so that for each of the actions get a different representation and avoid this problem. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It's interesting to see your log-policy gradient will become this form!. One common approach to extract action specific features is to use separate weight vectors for each action, where each weight vector is used to compute the feature for the corresponding action. For example with a shared set of weights to compute the stacked state features, one can apply a different transformation to these features for each action such as by *concatenating* one-hot encoding vector for each discrete action.